# SQL Server split string built in function vs old-style TVF for splitting string with SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following `Split` function which was used for a while now in conjunction with multi-valued parameters used for the purpose of SSRS Reports.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
     (@List NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @SplitOn NVARCHAR(5))  
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
                  (
                       Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                       Value NVARCHAR(100)
                  ) 
AS  
BEGIN
    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @List) > 0)
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)
            SELECT
                Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, 1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @List) - 1))) 
        SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @List) + LEN(@SplitOn), LEN(@List))
    END 

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)
        SELECT Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))

    RETURN
END
```

This method is somewhat cumbersome, but I noticed that since we had an upgrade of our version of SQL Server we are on it now supports the `String_Split` which is a built-in function.

My question is for anyone in the know who has used this: can this be used to replace the function shown above entirely for multi-value parameters?

Thank you in advance

Comment: String_Split() has one drawback... it does not gtd the sequence.   Additionally, looping should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Hi Thanks, is there a better way then the one I used above and also one that would avoid looping? I suppose the ordering is important from an end user point of view if its all alphabetical. Is there a way to do it in order using String_Split() and somehow order it?

Comment: See an example below

Answer (score 2):

If 2016+, I like the JSON approach.  If not 2016+ ... there is an XML approach as well.

**Example**

```
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-JSON]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       Dog
2       Cat
3       House
4       Car
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-JSON] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
          ,RetVal = Value
     From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(replace(@String,'"','\"'),@Delimiter,'","')+'"]' )
);
```

Comment: Thank you John, I will need play around with what you sent, never used JSON In SQL so should be a interesting. So am I correct in guessing I would still need to use TVF particularly if I want to order the list in the parameters? There is no way to do without using an TFV with the use of String_Split alone? Your solution above looks good as it does away using the loop :)

Comment: @abs786123 string_split() is a TVF.   If you don't care about the sequence, then string_split() is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Simple but should do the job

```
DECLARE @list varchar(max) = 'john, bob, dave'

SELECT txt
    FROM (SELECT ltrim(rtrim([Value])) as txt from string_split(@list, ',')) s 
    ORDER BY txt
```

returns

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you guys, I am kind of deviating from the main question now, but if there was a Single Quote say on a name like O'Hare, can this be used to take care of that as names are added all the time and I will be non the wiser? thank you

Comment: That would have to be handled by whatever builds the delimted string. You could use a pipe `|` to separate as that's less likely to be used also, but the single quote/apostrophe issue would still have to be addressed.